# Nest functions in Lisp `if` operator

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have this `if` code in Common Lisp:

```
(if (= 1 1) ((write "Hello") NIL)  (else-function...))
```

Obviously, 1 = 1, I would like to do this:

if the condition (in this case 1 = 1) is true, then I would like to print "Hello" AND return `NIL`. How can I do this? From what I understand I can only do one of these two actions.

Should I use a lambda to print and return `NIL` at the same time?

Comment: see the special operator `PROGN`

Comment: @RainerJoswig that works great thanks. feel free to answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to compose expressions into sequential execution (first do this, then do this, finally return this), you need to wrap them into something, unless you are more or less scripting at toplevel.

The most basic construct for this is `progn`, which evaluates all the given forms in sequence and finally returns the values of the last.  Many constructs in Common Lisp have an *implicit* `progn`, e. g. function bodies, let bodies, etc.  There are also `prog1` and `prog2` which do the same, but return the values of the first or second form after the operator, respectively.

So, `progn` is what you should use here.

However, if you only have a consequent, no else clause, you can use `when` instead of `if`.  `When` has an implicit `progn`.  There is also `unless`, for when you only have an else clause, no consequent.

It should be noted that there are other composing constructs for other needs: `block` allows using an explicit `return-from` form to determine the values at runtime.  `Tagbody` allows using `go` to jump around in it (but doesn't return anything, you'd need an additional block around to do that).  These are mostly useful for creating new control structures (e. g. in macros).